# Don't play phone ringtone if bluetooth headset is connected

Tags: bluetooth, ringtone, bluetooth-audio

We recently got rid of our landline and were are now using a 1st gen Republic Wireless Moto E as our home phone. We also bought Vtech Connect to Cell phones so we'd have a more home phone like experience. As far as the Moto E is concerned, the cordless phone is just a bluetooth headset. We we get a call, the cordless phones ring, and the Moto E itself also rings. We really only need the cordless phones to ring, not the phone itself. My mom uses this Moto E as her cell phone when we are out of the house, so setting a silent ringtone on the Moto E isn't really practical. Is there a way make the Moto E itself not ring while it's connected to the bluetooth cordless phones?